# Why can't I set username for a Facebook Page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

When I go to http://www.facebook.com/username/ I can only see a drop down list with my pages but no input field where I could enter my desired username. What can be wrong?

Are there some restrictions on creating page usernames? Haven't found anything in http://www.facebook.com/help/pages/usernames.

Comment: I've just read somewhere that the page needs to have at least 25 likes to be eligible for a username. Is that true? Haven't found a mention in FB Help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, when creating a username for a FB page, your page needs to have 25 likes. Once you have that, you can set the username. Just make sure you want to stick with the username you choose. Once you set a username, you cannot change it.

Comment: Like counts doesn't matter to create username for FB page. See [Facebook Help Team](https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=440314586091341&answer_id=443904599065673).

Answer (score 0):

You indeed have to add a mobile phone number where you get an SMS from Facebook with a code, and only after this you can set your page username.

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]! This looks like a comment/upvote to this answer: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/139073/136642; there's no need to repeat it.

Answer (score -1):

You have to add a mobile phone number to your Facebook account settings to verify your page and then you set up a user name.  Google videos on it.  I found a guy that posted a video to show how it works.  I only have 1 like on my page, so it is not based upon likes.