# When does a Facebook page qualify to have a web address?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

I have created two Facebook pages, both never published so far, first on March, 9 and second today. While I had absolutely no problems with setting Facebook Web Address for the first page, it seems, that I can't do this for the second one:

1. When I visit my page's `About` section and click on `Enter a Facebook web address` link, I see message saying `Your page needs at least 25 fans to have a web address`.
2. When I visit (as [instructed](https://www.facebook.com/help/409473442437047)) [facebook.com/username](https://www.facebook.com/username), when logged in as regular user (not as page), select my page in `Page` dropdown, enter desired name and click `Check availability`,  I see confirmation, that my name is valid. But when I click `Confirm`, a message pops, saying that my page does not qualify to have a username.

I have read these questions and answers:

1. [Facebook says vanity URL for page is not available, but it is not used by another page](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/68978/facebook-says-vanity-url-for-page-is-not-available-but-it-is-not-used-by-anothe)
2. [Unable to set Facebook web address on new page](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/40188/unable-to-set-facebook-web-address-on-new-page)
3. [Why can't I set username for a Facebook Page?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/27965/why-cant-i-set-username-for-a-facebook-page)

But, it brought no help to me. All of them seems to be claiming, that I need 25 likes to be able to set Facebook Web Address for my webpage. If that's true, then how did I managed to set it for my first page? Both pages are *exactly the same* -- created, filled with very limited, basic info and unpublished. The *only* difference between them, is that first (where I was able to change vanity URL) has profile photo uploaded and the second one hasn't. But, I strongly doubt, that this could be the reason.

Was there any change in Facebook's web address creation policy or is there anything, that I didn't done, while I was supposed to do?

How it is possible, that I changed web URL for my first page, that was created three months ago, but I failed to do the same on a page created today?

Comment: Regarding the [link to my question (#2)](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/40188/unable-to-set-facebook-web-address-on-new-page/78767) - I was actually able to set the web address at some point _after_ the page had been created. However, the page had received no more than two likes, so I have no idea what the trigger was?! (It was also over 2 years ago and they've changed their policies a few times since then.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you created the page on the same time that page qualify to have a web address. Like count doesn't matter. See the [Facebook Help Team's answer](https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=440314586091341&answer_id=443904599065673) on the same question on help community.

I guess sometime Facebook randomly do this for security purpose. Just give a try, add a phone number in your account (in case you have not added) and verify that number. Then try to add a web address for your page from your account(as regular user).

Answer (score 0):

Newest fix and working 100%: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f-YbfvT-yl8.

A frame from the above video is:

> To recap, for it to really work, you need to add another admin to your page who is NOT yet an admin of any page. Then let him/her set the desired username.

Comment: Please summarize the video. If the link dies some day, the answer will be left useless.