# How to set URL or domain as Twitter's username?

Tags: twitter

I have a quite similar question to [this one](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/78764/21486), only this time concerning Twitter and user name, not URL.

Situation is nearly exactly the same. I have created my first Twitter account in the beginning of March and I have absolutely no problems in giving my account name containing an URL (my company's name includes it, so it seems natural to me).

Today I wanted to create another account, for the same company, but different langage and failed on `Account update failed: Name must not contain URLs` error message. What am I missing? Was there any change in Twitter policy or regulations around this corner?

**Update**: *It seems, that Twitter complies only on certain domains. For example, you account name can contain `.pl`, but can't contain `.com`. You also can't register a new Twitter account with `.com` domain in its name, but Twitter currently has some bugs around this, which cause to throw [an incorrect error messages](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/79015/21486) to user, who is attempting to register such account.*

Comment: Might as well roll with it as opposed to worrying about it. I use mikestrattonNET for my Twitter Screen Name. Some professional accounts will use ourwebsite_com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certain domain names (like `.com`) or URLs are prohibited and can't be used as usernames for Twitter accounts. However, you can try to "fool" Twitter and use the unicode character `One Dot Leader U+2024`, that looks like a dot.

Example:

```
domain․com
```

Many editors (like Notepad++) do not recognize this symbol (produces an empty box instead), but it can be copied to the clipboard (tested on Windows 7) and pasted to the `Edit profile` input box in Twitter.

Comment: I have confirmed, that your solution works like a charm. I have edited your answer a little bit (waiting in queue for peer-review) and my question's title, so your answer would answer it more directly and so I can accept your answer.