# How to sign up to Twitter?

Tags: twitter

It sounds strange, but I'm unable to sign up to Twitter.

When I try to use Google Chrome, the sign up form contains only `name` and `e-mail` fields. And even though all of them are filled-up and contain valid values (notice check-marks), I'm bumped with `Please complete all required fields` error every time, I click `Sign Up`:

[image]

When I'm using Opera, I'm able to see `username` additional field (but still no sign of `password` field), but I'm hitting the wall with the same error message, even though -- again -- all fields are correct:

[image]

When I try to use Internet Explorer, I can finally see all the four fields, but effect is exactly the same:

[image]

**What am I missing? I know, how much stupidity is in this question, but... how should I sing up to Twitter?**

BTW: In all my attempts (in all browsers), I'm trying to use my own e-mail and all the time it is the same, if that matters. When I tried to used some fake, probably not existing e-mail address, I managed to pass through this step. I closed web page after that, because -- quite naturally -- I want my Twitter account on my real e-mail, not on some fake one.

Comment: Are you sure you don't already have a twitter account? Try resetting your password first. If that doesn't work, maybe you could try registering with another e-mail address and after having successfully registered, change your e-mail.
The first one (opera) could be a bug but could also be an A/B test.

Comment: Yeap. The password reset form says, that they don't have such e-mail on records. Currently I'm further investigating this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem is directly linked to [this question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/78766/21486). I was trying to register a Twitter account, that contains `.com` in name (which is not allowed since [recently](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/78766/21486)).

There's a bug in Twitter, which causes to display error:

> Please complete all required fields

and mark `name` field as having correct value. While it actually should mark it as invalid (because it contains `.com` part, prohibited) and should display correct error message. Like for example:

> Account creation failed: Name must not contain URLs

Or something around that.

There's still, of course, an [open question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/78766/21486), when did they changed their rules (I managed to create an account containg `.com` in name about three months ago) and why do they limit domains prohibited in name to only a certain group (you can use `.pl` and probably many more ccTLDs in Twitter name)?

Comment: Had a similar problem today. Perhaps because my 'first name' was 'I'.